# Is it possible to make my modals use different and external css files

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage that has multi tabs on it, on each tab, I have a button that opens a specific  Modal form related to the tab content.

I already have a .css for my webpage, and what I'm trying to do is make my Modals use different CSS files...

Is it possible to do so? To make a Modal use a specific CSS different of the CSS of the webpage?
I am trying to avoid writing on the same CSS of the main webpage.

Hope you can help me out. And thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, if you use the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)

Comment: But it's hard to know exactly what the best solution to your problem is because you haven't specifed any code / [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There could be a much similar solution for your case...

Comment: This is a job for CSS classes. One approach is to make a class for each modal, or for each form. Whatever the case, just add the new rules to your main CSS file. You shouldn't have to think about multiple CSS files with what seems to be a simple context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try linking in two css files, both of which have **different** classes for modals (different titles). Then use each one. As long as the files don't contradict each other, you'll be fine. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="first_stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="second_stylesheet.css">
```

And later in the code:

```
<div class="modalfromstylesheet1">content</div>
<div class="modalfromstylesheet2">content</div>
```

Replace `<div>` with whatever element you use for your modal, and make sure that you reference the proper css class.

Or, another possible solution:

1. Link both files as shown above
2. In one file, have completely different class names
3. In the other file, have different class names

Then, for the modal:

```html
<div class="modalcontent">
  <p class="modalcontent">Text</p>
</div>
```

Set the class `modalcontent` in your css file(s) to change the specifics, and tag it to all items in the modal. This may seem a hard workaround, but it will work.